# Appending copys of objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort through a list "cards" in a player's hand, and create a new list of "cards" containing only those cards which are spades:

```
class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.hand = hand # hand is a list of 13 card objects

    def spades(self):
        spades = []
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.suit == 'spade':
                spades.append(copy.deepcopy(card))
        return spades
```

however, calling the spades() method outputs a list of cards of the same number and value of the last card in the hand, and the same length of the amount of spades. for instance:

```
players = deal()

for card in players[1].hand:
    print(str(card.value) + ' of ' + card.suit)

print("SPADES")

spades = players[1].spades()

for cards in spades:
     print(str(card.value) + 'of' + card.suit)
```

outputs:

```
6ofclub
13ofheart
4ofdiamond
7ofspade
13ofdiamond
13ofclub
11ofspade
8ofdiamond
3ofdiamond
10ofheart
8ofheart
12ofclub
12ofdiamond

SPADES
12ofdiamond
12ofdiamond
```

I think realize that the list "spades" is appending pointers to the variable "card", rather than new objects. However I thought that using copy or deep copy would have solved this issue.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that there's nothing wrong with this code. The problem is somewhere else, and we need a [mcve].

Comment: You need to post your `card` class as well; and `Player` instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, there is no problem in the code. The issue is with the print at the end...

You've written:

```
for cards in spades:
     print(str(card.value) + 'of' + card.suit)
```

So you're looping and getting `cards` but you're printing `card` which is from the previous for loop which is still assigned the variable from the last for loop's last iteration

Here's the entire code to reproduce the fix:

```
import copy


class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value) + " of " + str(self.suit)

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, hand):
        self.hand = hand # hand is a list of 13 card objects

    def spades(self):
        spades = []
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.suit == 'spade':
                spades.append(copy.deepcopy(card))
        return spades

vals = [i.split("of", 1) for i in """6ofclub
13ofheart
4ofdiamond
7ofspade
13ofdiamond
13ofclub
11ofspade
8ofdiamond
3ofdiamond
10ofheart
8ofheart
12ofclub
12ofdiamond""".strip().split()]

hand = [Card(i[0], i[1]) for i in vals]


players = [None, Player(hand)]

for card in players[1].hand:
    print(card)

print()
spades = players[1].spades()

print("SPADES")
for cards in spades:
     print(cards)  # <----- Print card*s* not card.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by changing the spades() method but not entirely sure why it worked:

```
def spades(self):
    spades = []
    for card in self.hand:
        if card.suit == 'spade':
            copy = deepcopy(card)
            spades.append(copy)
    return spades
```

I assigned the deep copy to a variable first, then passed the variable through append(). This seems like a trivial change to me...if anyone has an explanation of this behavior it would be much appreciated.